# Flutter/Firebase Realtime database: how to use equalsTo?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My db structure looks like this:

[image]

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
databaseReference
    .child('orders')
    .equalTo(myUID, key: 'uid')
    .orderByChild(orderField)
    .limitToFirst(pageSize)
.once()
.then((snapshot) {

  // form current list
  List<dynamic> curretList = [];
  snapshot.value.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
      curretList.add(orderData);
  });
```

But the following query is returning null result.

I suspect the error is in `.equalTo(Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).uid, key: 'uid')`. Did I use `equalTo` correctly here?

Comment: What is `orderField`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen order field is negative_epoch

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `equalTo` that you're trying to use does something completely different than what you need here.

What you're looking for is:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
databaseReference
    .child('orders')
    .orderByChild('uid')
    .equalTo(myUID)
    .limitToFirst(pageSize)
```

So this takes all child nodes of `orders`, sorts them on the value of their `uid` property, and then returns the first `pageSize` nodes that have a `uid` value equal to `myUID`.

Since you can only have one `orderBy...` call per query, this means you'll have to reorder the results by timestamp in your application code. Also see [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: what if I want to keep my original sort order?

Comment: Also, I have pagination in place, so sorting in application code doesn't work!

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer to the question I linked.